# Let $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are real polynomials in $x, y\in R$. Why does $A \subseteq B$?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let  $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ are real polynomials in $x, y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose

$A = \left\{ {x + iy:x,y \in \mathbb{R},\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} p(x,y) + q(x,y) = 0} \right\}$ and $B = \left\{ {x + iy:x,y \in \mathbb{R},({x^2} + {y^2})p{{(x,y)}^2} - q{{(x,y)}^2} = 0} \right\}$.

Why does $A \subseteq B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$(x^2+y^2)p^2-q^2=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,p+q\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,p-q\right)$$